# How to set plural collection name in C# mongo driver?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the MongoDB default C# driver. In my code, I have created an entity (collection) with the name of Customer.
Is there a default convention or class attribute that will set the pluralized version of my collection name in MongoDB ('customers') ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any so I'm using the [Humanizer](http://humanizr.net/) library to pluralize the names. I actually go a step further and use the type itself to create a collection:

```
var customers = database.GetCollection(typeof(Customer).Name.Pluralize().ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an external library suggested by I3arnon you can use the .NET pluralizing service available in the  `System.Data.Entity.Design` assembly.

You can use it like this:

```
 var serv = PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));
 var plural = serv.Pluralize(typeof(Person).Name);
```

It will correctly pluralize **Person** to **People** or **Customer** to **Customers** like in the example above. It is the same mechanism used by Entity Framework pluralization.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same issue, so I wrote a simple wrapper around the .NET MongoDB driver to automate object to collection name mapping. It uses  `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices` under the hood, so it doesn't rely on any external dependencies. It may save you a few lines of code.

If you're interested: https://github.com/MikePennington/Mongonizer